# Excluding certain values from an xsl:sum equation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Within my stylesheet, I have an xsl:variable that looks into the XML, looks at a list of objects and returns the sum of the price value from each object, my code for that is exampled below:

```
  <xsl:variable name="ExampleTotal">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(/ListOfObjects/Object/PriceOfObject)"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

And this works fine,
My problem is that I don't need the sum of **every** one of these objects in the list, only the ones that contain a value of being **true**.

Example XML:

```
<ListOfObjects>
  <Object>
    <PriceOfObject>35.00</PriceOfObject>
    <PriceNeeded>true</PriceNeeded>
    <OtherData>example</OtherData>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <PriceOfObject>36.00</PriceOfObject>
    <PriceNeeded>true</PriceNeeded>
    <OtherData>example</OtherData>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <PriceOfObject>35.00</PriceOfObject>
    <PriceNeeded>true</PriceNeeded>
    <OtherData>example</OtherData>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <PriceOfObject>33.00</PriceOfObject>
    <PriceNeeded>false</PriceNeeded>
    <OtherData>example</OtherData>
 </Object>
</ListOfObjects>
```

is it possible to look through the list of objects and only sum up the total of the ones that have the  value as true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="ExampleTotal">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(/ListOfObjects/Object[PriceNeeded='true']/PriceOfObject)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Above code changed as suggested by Michael Kay,

```
<xsl:variable name="ExampleTotal" 
  select="sum(/ListOfO‌​bjects/Object[PriceNe‌​eded='true']/PriceOfO‌​bject)"/>
```

Comment: Even better would be `<xsl:variable name="ExampleTotal" select="sum(/ListOfObjects/Object[PriceNeeded='true']/PriceOfObject)"/>`. There's no need here for the redundant code to convert the numeric sum into a result tree fragment, since it will almost certainly be converted back to a number when used.